# function declaration in pro*C without body

Tags: c++, c

> Based on the comments i ve changed the subject to pro*c code and i
>   withdraw the claim that it is C++ syntax. Keeping the tags same; as i
>   still hope it is similar to c++ and no Pro*C tag available please bear
>   with it.

I suppose its a very new bee question. But as i have no ample time to learn C++ documentation i would appreciate if i can get help on this.

I am working on converting pro*C code which resembles C++ syntax.

Here is the code snippet

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <prg_codes.h>
#include <prg_defines.h>

typedef struct
{
   int errorflag;
   int slot;
} option_info;


int calc_options(currArgc,currArgv,options)
int currArgc;
char *currArgv[];
option_info *options;
{   
   int optChar;
   int invopt=0;
 while ((optChar = getopt(currArgc, currArgv, ":s:")) != -1 && !(invopt))
  {}
   /* other commands */

}  


void  main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    option_info options;     
    int rc = 0;
    rc=calc_options(argc,argv,&options);
    /* other commands */

}
```

My question is

`option_info` is defined as a struct then as a function and called from main. Is it fine? how does it work?

Is `option_info` inside the function `calc_options`. Because option_info seems using the parameters defined in calc_options.

Or `calc_options` body is written somewhere else in any other file in the include section ?

Comment: The declaration syntax for the function is Kernighan & Ritchie C (from the 1970's), it's not supported in C++. Also, `void main` is invalid in both C and C++. Contrary to your claim `option_info` is only defined as a `struct`, not as a function, *but* C and C++ allow using the same name for a `struct` and a function.

Comment: but this link http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/fcdb/oracle/or-proc.html#overview  says pro*c code follows same C/C++ syntax

Comment: Regarding the "but" there are three possibilities: (1) your interpretation of what you read at that page is wrong, or (2) what's at that page is wrong, or (3) you perceive a contradiction where there is none.

Comment: "i have no ample time to learn C++ documentation". You are going to have a rough time with this project. Consider hiring someone.

Comment: i m the one hired :). but for different objective

Comment: @user1016198 The link says no such thing about the syntax.

Comment: @user1016198 `First, the Pro*C precompiler recognizes the SQL statements embedded in the program, and replaces them with appropriate calls to the functions in the SQL runtime library. The output is pure C/C++ code with all the pure C/C++ portions intact. Then, a regular C/C++ compiler is used to compile the code and produces the executable.` This code has its own syntax. It will only be converted by the compiler into C/C++ code. I guess you didn't even read the overview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This snippet is in the archaic K&R C syntax** which predates ANSI C. Then it is indented strangely which makes it look at first glance like you describe, but it really isn't. `calc_options` is the function definition with three arguments, the 3rd of which is a pointer `options` to typedef option_info.

This is the same thing in ANSI C syntax, so it is easier to read:

```
int calc_options(int currArgc, char *currArgv[], option_info *options)
{
  int optChar;
  int invopt=0;
  while ((optChar = getopt(currArgc, currArgv, ":s:")) != -1 && !(invopt))
  {}
  /* other commands */
}
```

"option_info is defined as a struct" **Yes** (well a typedef to a struct)

"then as a function and called from main". **No**

"Is it fine?" **Yes** (but should be changed to ANSI syntax)

"how does it work?" **Pretty good**

"Is option_info inside the function calc_options?" **It is the type of the 3rd argument `options`**

"Because option_info seems using the parameters defined in calc_options." **It *is* the type of parameter `options`**

"Or calc_options body is written somewhere else in any other file in the include section ?" **Nope**

Comment: thanks a lot. really appreciate your effort. even after the question seems unacceptable .

Comment: It fooled me for a second too, it does look weird. Cheers, good luck.